# how to change the replication color indicator adobe aem

Tags: adobe, replication, aem

The replication color indicator for successful activation of content in Adobe AEM is GREEN.

How can I change this to a different color. Say, for example, I want GREEN to be the indicator for successful Author to Publish replication and Yellow to be the indicator for successful Author to Author replication.

I tried to google to get this information and went through some code under the replication section in /libs and I am heading no where.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not track replication for same content vs different environments (or replication queues), replication status is green if content is replicated successfully on all configured queues. So i doubt if its OOB Possible to identify if content is replicated on one environment and not on other.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the CSS for the associated class for each replication.
For example: the "deactivated" class is *"#CQ .cq-siteadmin-wrapper .status-deactivated"*

Try adding a custom background-image attribute into your CSS file for your desired image/color.